# How to show the colpos id after the name in TYPO3 Backend layout?

Tags: typo3, tca

I have  a need to show for tt_content records the id of the colpos for regular editors on the production website, for now it is only shown in my development space website.
[image: Column colPos with id in brackets]

do you have an idea how to add it ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom [`itemsProcFunc`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/12.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/ItemsProcFunc.html#tca-property-itemsprocfunc) for the `select` field which is used for the `colPos` column here. Use [TCA overrides](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/ExtendingTca/Index.html) to register it accordingly:

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule(
    original: $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'],
    overrule: [
        'columns' => [
            'colPos' => [
                'config' => [
                    'itemsProcFunc' => \VENDOR\Extension\UserFunction\FormEngine\ItemProcessor::class . '->appendValueToLabel',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
);
```

The `ItemProcessor` class:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace VENDOR\Extension\UserFunction\FormEngine;

final class ItemProcessor
{
    public function appendValueToLabel(array &$params): void
    {
        foreach ($params['items'] as &$item) {
            $item['label'] = sprintf('%s [%s]', $item['label'], $item['value']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias! I will try this solution.

Comment: it show an error in the backend 
An error occurred trying to process items for field "Column" (PHP Warning: Undefined array key "label" in ext_localconf.php line 371).
and instead of the label it shows "INVALID VALUE".

Comment: The error sounds weird since the code is not put in the `ext_localconf.php`. Better ask in the TYPO3 Slack about this.

Comment: I had to put the ItemProcessor class: in the ext_localconf.php file can you please tell me where better to put in ?

Comment: Explaining basics of PHP programming is out of scope here, so maybe start with that. And again, better continue in the TYPO3 Slack now.